# Radio Group value selection issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have following radiogroup:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rd_male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rd_female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

I want to get the selected value in this radio group, hence i written following code in onCreate method:

```
 int checkedRadioButton = rgGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


            switch (checkedRadioButton) {
            case R.id.rd_male : gender = "Female";
                                      break;
            case R.id.rd_female : gender = "Male";
                                     break;

          }
```

But every time i finds that value of variable gender is "Female" only (Although i selects male)

What is wrong in this code?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple mistake**

```
switch (checkedRadioButton) {
            case R.id.rd_male : gender = "Male";
                                      break;
            case R.id.rd_female : gender = "Female";
                                     break;

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have made a very silly mistake...Change with:

```
switch (checkedRadioButton) {
        case R.id.rd_male : gender = "Male";
                                  break;
        case R.id.rd_female : gender = "Female";
                                 break;

      }
```